# mysql how to create new row for selected group

Tags: mysql

I have tables with partners, publications, baskets, etc. I'd add a publication for every partner who in the selected basket.

Every table connect with keys, not sure, have i join them (`partner.partner_id`, `publications.pb_partner_id`, `baskets.bsk_partner_id`).

I tried this but it isn't good enough:

```
INSERT INTO publications(pb_id, timestamp, comment) 
VALUES (1, 2017, 'whatever') 
WHERE (SELECT partner_id 
FROM partner JOIN basket ON partner_id = b_partner_id WHERE b_partner_id IN basket_id = 13;
```

Yes, I'm a full beginner in, so it may be simple, but i dont speak english well enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use insert into ...select in the following way:

```
INSERT INTO publications(pb_id, timestamp, comment) (SELECT 1, 2017,partner_id FROM partner JOIN basket ON partner_id = b_partner_id WHERE  basket_id = 13);
```